# Issue in installing Facebook Seamless Communication on Mac

Tags: python, facebook

I tried to install seamless_communication from Facebook on MacOS With Intel CPU. The error we get is:

```
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of fairseq2 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fairseq2n==0.1.1 (from fairseq2) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fairseq2n==0.1.1
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Older than 3.8?

Comment: I'm using 3.11.4

Comment: What does `pip --version` output? Replace `pip` with however you were originally invoking pip`

Comment: pip version is 23.2.1

Comment: Can you provide the full output (with an [edit])? The part after "from" helps us understand your environment

Comment: It is my full output. There is just one other line which says: processing /PATH/